# SELECT using schema name

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue with psql. I am trying to select the records from a table but psql acts like the table doesnt exist. I have tried finding it and found that it resides in the 'public' schema. I have tried selecting from this table like so:

```
highways=# SELECT * FROM public.CLUSTER_128000M;
```

This does not work stating the following:

```
ERROR: relation 'public.CLUSTER_128000M' does not exist
```

I know that it definetly exists and that it is definetly in the 'public' schema so how can I perform a select statement on it?

#### Edit:

This was caused by useing FME to create my tables. As a result FME used " marks on the table names making them case sensitive. To reverse this see the comments below.

Comment: Did you maybe forget the double quotes around "CLUSTER_128000M" ?

Comment: Yes I did. *facepalm* The examples I have seen did not stipulate double quotes so I did not know it needed them. If you put that as an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: This behaviour is caused by the fact that you *created* the table using double quotes. Therefor the name is now case-sensitive and you need to use them *always*. If you avoid using double quotes completely then you'll never run into this issue again.

Comment: Is there any way to rectify this afterwards? The tables were created by FME.

Comment: SQL command to convert to case-insensitive: `ALTER TABLE "SOME_NAME" RENAME TO some_name`

Comment: Thanks you very much Daniel. Thats fantastic.

Comment: Can someone add their answer in the form of an answer so that I can accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the third party software FME using quotes around the names of the tables at time of creation. The solution to make the tables useable again was to use the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE "SOME_NAME" RENAME TO some_name
```